# results.row[i] is undefined using react-native-db-models

Tags: react-native

Im new to React Native and Im using react-native-db-models. I have searched stackoverflow for fetching the data and it gave me this code below

```
DB.users.get_all((result) => {
  let data = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= result.totalrows; i++) {
    data.push(result.rows[i]);
  }
```

but **result.rows[i]** returns undefined. Any ideas how and why?
I tried my own solution but this time it gave me another problem. This is my code

```
DB.expense.get_all(function(result){
      var data = [];
      for (let i = 1; i <= result.totalrows; i++) {
        let j = result.autoinc;
        let id = j - i;
        DB.expense.get_id(id, function(results){
          data.push(result)
        })
      }
}
```

when I put ***console.log(data)*** after **data.push(result)** it works fine. But when I put ***console.log(data)*** outside DB.expense.get_id function, **console.log(data)** returns an empty array.
I really need your help guys

Comment: Are you skipping the first result on purpose? Indexes in javascript start at 0.

Comment: @ShannonHicks doesnt matter, still the same output when it starts with 0